# How to get dataItems of selectedKeyNames of checked row across all pages in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I have Kendo grid with local data and check box and pagination. I am getting all checked items Id using selectedKeynames() across all pages.
How can I get dataItems of checked iems across all pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kendo for paging, sorting and so on and not handling these operations on the server, then there seems to be no other way than skimming over the list of elements in the datasource. Something like this:

```js
var g = $("#grid").getKendoGrid();
var d = g.dataSource.data();
var s = g.selectedKeyNames();
var r = [];
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
  if (s.indexOf(d[i].Id) >= 0) {
    r.push(d[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: That will result the current page data. I need all checked dataItems across all pages

Comment: I can get the checked Ids using $("#grid").getKendoGrid().selectedKeyNames().How can I skimming over datasource using checked Ids?

Comment: I've extend my answer with an example of how to collect all selected items.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution for you.

Please review the following dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/ibALanIX

As with the other solution I am obtaining the data but using a forEach loop on the selected items as when you start having a large number of records the for loop could take some time.

So all I am doing is going over the selected items and then grabbing those items from the selected list.

```
 var grid = $("#rowSelection").data('kendoGrid');
 var selectedItems = grid.selectedKeyNames();
 var actualItems = [];


 if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
   selectedItems.forEach(function(key) {
     actualItems.push(grid.dataSource.get(key));
   });


 }
```

This would then reduce the number of loops you are having to do and as you know what the keys are from the selection, then this just uses the default get method of the kendo DataSource which maps to the ID of the model in the datasource schema.